# SQL query to return only 1 record per group ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm looking for a way to handle the following scenario. I have a database table that I need to return only one record for each "group id" that is contained within the table, furthermore the record that is selected within each group should be the oldest person in the household.

```
ID   Group ID   Name               Age
1   134        John Bowers        37
2   134        Kerri Bowers       33
3   135        John Bowers        44
4   135        Shannon Bowers     42
```

So in the sample data provided above I would need ID 1 and 3 returned, as they are the oldest people within each group id.

This is being queried against a SQL Server 2005 database.

Comment: If you want the name, you still have the chance of choosing >1 row if you have >1 person with the oldest age.  You should also establish criteria on what name to pick as well in that case.

Comment: Good point Chris. Is was trying to simplifiy the question a little, but that leaves holes like these :-) I actually have another field for gender, so I'm looking to select the oldest male within a household. if there is to male, then the oldest female. In the event that there are two males in the same household with the same age then I need to select only 1 of the records. This could be basied on something as simple as the person with the lowest ID number for the tie breaker.

Comment: There's a good discussion of this sort of problem in section 21.4, "Extrema Functions", of Joe Celko's excellent book "SQL for Smarties".  If you're going to be running into anything trickier than simple SELECTs and INSERTs, I highly recommend this book.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT groupid
        FROM    mytable
        ) mo
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.groupid = mo.groupid
        ORDER BY
                age DESC
        ) t
```

or this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY groupid ORDER BY age DESC) rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) x
WHERE   x.rn = 1
```

This will return at most one record per group even in case of ties.

See this article in my blog for performance comparisons of both methods:

- [**SQL Server: Selecting records holding group-wise maximum**](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/30/sql-server-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum/)

Comment: +1: Yeah, forgot my disclaimer about the ties.  Too busy fighting fires.

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi. I was able to add the gender column in addtion to the age column in your ORDER By clause and get the results that I was looking for! (The gender column was only discussed in a comment after my initial question) Your solution is perfect, and adaptable!

Comment: Follow up question. These is going to be run against 175 million records. Is one or the other query more efficient?

Comment: `@Richard West`: how many distinct groups do you have? Do you have a separate table that would contain the groups?

Comment: For some reason SQL Server gives me `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'`.

Comment: I needed this exact thing and the one with the Cross Apply wasn't working at all. It would remove entire records that should have been a group of 1, whereas in some other situations, it wouldn't. Just didn't work.

Comment: @Ristogod: could you please clarify what you mean by "exact same thing"? Are you saying that you had created the setup from the post and the query retuned incorrect results when you ran it?

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t.groupid,
       t.name
  FROM TABLE t
  JOIN (SELECT t.groupid,
               MAX(t.age) 'max_age'
          FROM TABLE t
      GROUP BY t.groupid) x ON x.groupid = t.groupid
                           AND x.max_age = t.age
```

So what if there's 2+ people with the same age for a group?  It'd be better to store the birthdate rather than age - you can always calculate the age for presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming *Group* is synonym for *Household*)

```
Select * From Table t
Where Age = (Select Max(Age)
             From Table 
             Where GroupId = t.GroupId)
```

If there are two or more "oldest" people in some household (They all are the same age and there is noone else older), then this will return all of them, not just one at random.

If this is an issue, then you need to add another subquery to return an arbitrary key value for one person in that set.

```
Select * From Table t
Where Id = 
  (Select Max(Id) Fom Table 
   Where GroupId = t.GroupId
      And Age =
         (Select(Max(Age) From Table
          Where GroupId = t.GroupId))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GroupID, Name, Age
FROM table
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT GroupID, MAX(Age) AS OLDEST
FROM table
) AS OLDESTPEOPLE
ON
table.GroupID = OLDESTPEOPLE.GroupID
AND
table.Age = OLDESTPEOPLE.OLDEST
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GroupID, Name, Age
FROM table
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT GroupID, MAX(Age) AS OLDEST
FROM table
**GROUP BY GroupID**
) AS OLDESTPEOPLE
ON
table.GroupID = OLDESTPEOPLE.GroupID
AND
table.Age = OLDESTPEOPLE.OLDEST
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).